# configparser does not show sections

Tags: python, configparser

I added sections and its values to ini file, but configparser doesn't want to print what sections I have in total. What I've done:

```
import configparser
import os


# creating path
current_path = os.getcwd()
path = 'ini'
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError:
    print("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)


# add section and its values
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['section-1'] = {'somekey' : 'somevalue'}
file = open(f'ini/inifile.ini', 'a')
with file as f:
    config.write(f)
file.close()

# get sections
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
file = open(f'ini/inifile.ini')
with file as f:
    config.read(f)
    print(config.sections())
file.close()
```

returns

> []

The similar code was [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/configparser.html), but doesn't work. What I do wrong and how I could solve this problem?

Comment: FYI, The `with` statement will close it for you, so there's no need to assign to the variable file. Just use `with open("...", "a") as f:` and drop the `close()`.

Comment: From the docs, `config.read` takes in a *filename*, not a file descriptor object. I.e. `config.read("ini/inifile.ini")`. If you want to use a file descriptor object, instead use `config.read_file(f)`.

Comment: @alkasm Thank you! You can write it as an answer to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read), `config.read()` takes in a *filename* (or list of them), not a file descriptor object:

> **`read`**`(`*`filenames, encoding=None`*`)`
>
> Attempt to read and parse an **iterable of filenames**, returning a list of filenames which were successfully parsed.
>
> If filenames is a string, a bytes object or a path-like object, it is treated as a single filename. ...
>
> **If none of the named files exist, the ConfigParser instance will contain an empty dataset**. ...

A file object is an iterable of strings, so basically the config parser is trying to read each string in the file as a filename. Which is sort of interesting and silly, because if you passed it a file that contained the filename of your actual config...it would work.

Anyways, you should pass the filename directly to `config.read()`, i.e.
    config.read("ini/inifile.ini")

Or, if you want to use a file descriptor object instead, simply use `config.read_file(f)`. Read the [docs for `read_file()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_file) for more information.

---

As an aside, you are duplicating some of the work the context manager is doing for no gain. You can use the `with` block without creating the object explicitly first or closing it after (it will get closed automatically). Keep it simple:

```
with open("path/to/file.txt") as f:
    do_stuff_with_file(f)
```